# The coefficient $p_{c'}^{c}$ in a formula in Lusztig's canonical basis paper

Tags: rt.representation-theory

In Lusztig's paper [Canonical bases arising from quantized enveloping algebras](https://www.ams.org/journals/jams/1990-03-02/S0894-0347-1990-1035415-6/S0894-0347-1990-1035415-6.pdf), the formula (a) in Section 9.4 on page 483, there is a formula
\begin{align}
\tilde{\gamma}_c' = \sum_{c' \le c} p_{c'}^c \gamma_{c'}'.
\end{align}
It is said that the coefficient $p_{c'}^c$ is the (formal) alternating sum of the eigenvalues of the Frobenius map on the stalks of the cohomology sheaves of $\mathcal{P}_c$ at any $F_q$ rational point of $\mathcal{O}_{c'}$. In the paper [Nilpotent orbits of linear and cyclic quivers and Kazhdan-Lusztig polynomials of type A](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0501054.pdf), on pages (3), (4), it is said that $p_{c'}^c$ is related Kazhdan-Lusztig polynomials. Is there some results in type $D, E$ in the literature about the coefficient $p_{c'}^c$? Are they also relate to Kazhdan-Lusztig polynomials? Thank you very much.